# Extract year, extract month from Joomla database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I need a code that checks Joomla MySQL database and depending on the year and depending on the month pulls data from there. I can extract a single quote, but cannot find the way to extract data only by year and/or only by month.

```
$query->where($db->quoteName('receive_date') . ' = '. $db->quote('2012-11-08 17:47:00'));
```

What is the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the fish or do you want to learn how to fish?  If the latter, read [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: I want to learn how to fish!

Comment: but I cannot find where to read about how to extract from the data only the year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the mysql YEAR() function on a date column will return the YEAR.

Using MONTH() on a date column will return the MONTH.

This example (untested but should work) should put you on the right track:

```
$query->where('YEAR('.$db->quoteName('receive_date').')  = '. $db->quote('2012'));
```